# How to use MembershipValidatePasswordEventHandler?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, configuration, asp.net-membership

Is there any way to put some restriction on password selection while creating new user with asp. net Membership.??

Condition Like
  **Password strength:**

- Minimum of 8 characters, with character complexity enforced. ie: Not contain the user's account name
- Be at least eight characters in length
- Contain characters from three of the following four categories:

English uppercase characters (A through Z)
English lowercase characters (a through z)
Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need to make some modifications to your Web.config. Find the following section and change it accordingly

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

**UPDATED**

First, update your membership config section in web.config like following

```
  <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Then, In your Account Controller, replace your Registration action(the one decorated with `[HttpPost]`) with the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    Membership.ValidatingPassword += new MembershipValidatePasswordEventHandler(OnValidatePassword);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
        Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
 }
```

And finally add the code for OnValidatePassword below the Registration Action

```
public void OnValidatePassword(object sender,
                          ValidatePasswordEventArgs args)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r =
          new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?=.{8,})(?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*\W){1,})");

    if (!r.IsMatch(args.Password))
    {
        args.FailureInformation =
              new HttpException("Password must be at least 8 characters long and " +
                                "contain at least one number and one special character.");
        args.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you achieve what you want !!

Comment: Pankaj check my updated question . And help me out in that context.

Comment: If you have this section then update it or else add it with changes to `minRequiredPasswordLength="8"` and `minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" .... For other requirements, you will need to do play with the membership class and use validations.

Comment: Pankaj have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx is this link relevant (MembershipValidatePasswordEventHandler)

Comment: For other requirements, you will need to do play with the membership class and use validations.....HOW?

Comment: Well, the link you provided basically provides you an instructions on implementing your own membership provider. This link [Password validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipvalidatepasswordeventhandler.aspx) is concerned with your requirements

Comment: Pankaj i have no idea how to work with above stuff and membership classes. It is better if you provide me some live example/link to decorate password strength. Or guide me step by step any help ll'b appreciated

Comment: @Kannas, I have updated my answer, hope it can help you achieve what you want

Comment: Thanx Pankaj for your help and time i really appreciate it....its time to try it now

Comment: Membership.ValidatingPassword += new MembershipValidatePasswordEventHandler(OnValidatePassword); can you please brief describe it??

Comment: The MembershipValidatePasswordEventHandler is a delegate and is defined for the ValidatingPassword event for a membership provider. The ValidatingPassword event is raised when the CreateUser method, the ChangePassword method, or the ResetPassword method of a membership provider is called.

Comment: passwordStrengthRegularExpression . I searched over google and found this.