# ASP .Net Membership (Where control goes on creating new user from config. window?)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Here is my Web.config file

```
<membership>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8"  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])$" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Here i want to restrict new user password with few conditions::

**Password strength:**

1. Contain characters from three of the following four categories:
   English uppercase characters (A through Z)
   English lowercase characters (a through z)
   Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
   Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %)
   -
2. **password Not contain the user's account name**

As you can see there is passwordStrengthRegularExpression attribute i used in web.config section to match 1st condition( that Membership provide).
Need solution to achieve second condition.

**In short**:: I need to customize membership to match  condition(character complexity enforced. ie:password Not contain the user's account name)
**Updated::**

I did what Eranga suggested me in my application . Now i also want to Display appropriate message when Membership createUser fails(on several customized condition).

Comment: i updated my question . have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sub class from your default provider and handle the [ValidatingPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.validatingpassword.aspx) event. There you can cancel the validation if it does not meet your second criteria.

```
public class MyMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider 
{
    public MyMembershipProvider()
    {
        ValidatingPassword += ValidatePassword;
    }

    void ValidatePassword(object sender, ValidatePasswordEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Password.Contains(e.UserName))
         {
             e.Cancel = true;
             e.FailureInformation = new Exception("blah blah");
         }
    }
}
```

Your `Web.Config` file should include the following. Make sure you give the full name of your custom membership class for the `type` attribute.

```
   <membership>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="MyNamespace.MyMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8"  minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!%,.;:])$" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: you mean customize membership??How can i use that subclass from web.config file??

Comment: Thanx eranga i'll try and let you know if it works for me. Suggest me the possible changes web.config required?

Comment: @Kannas Updated my answer to include the config changes.

Comment: @Kannas `namespace+class name` like in `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider`

Comment: @Kannas SqlMembershipProvider does not throw the exception when you `CreateUser` but will throw on `ChangePassword`. However you can show a custom error message to the user by inspecting the `MembershipCreateStatus` out parameter of the `CreateUser` method.

Comment: @Kannas You can either override that method or when you call it through `Membership.CreateUser(` call.

Comment: How? do u have link of some live examples?

Answer (score 1):

It's not MVC, but you can look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validatingpassword.aspx) of overriding the static event.  Also, since this is basically [the same question you asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784872/how-to-use-membershipvalidatepasswordeventhandler), with a little bit more detail, perhaps you could have just updated the original question?